# What settings are the most energy efficient on a Nook Color?

Tags: nook, hardware

I have seen some touch screen readers that have a gray on black background scheme that helps to reduce the power consumption and increase battery life. But those settings do not really exist on the Nook Color that I can find.  What setting is more efficient, and does it save any significant amount of battery life? Is there any way to do a custom color set?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the best way to save battery on a NOOK Color (or any device) is to:

- Lower the brightness
- Turn off Wifi and Bluetooth unless necessary

These two steps can more than double your battery life on some devices.